# ngModel creating an object property on null object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

Currently I am experimenting with template driving forms in Angular 17, I have the object interfaces

```
interface test2 = {
    name : string
}

interface test = {
    name : string,
    another? : test2
}
```

and I am creating the object like

```
let obj : test = { name: "moo", another: null };
```

and then in the page I have a simple input

```
<input name="tester" [(ngModel)]="obj.another.name">
```

Which will crash and burn. Doing

```
<input name="tester" [(ngModel)]="obj.another && obj.another.name">
```

will allow it to display the page but not create the object when data is entered into the field. Is there anyway for Angular to create the object of test2 when the object is null and assign its value when data is entered in the field? This used to work in AngularJS.

This will allow me to set the objects to null unless someone has entered data.

Cheers

Comment: why are you accessing over the `test2` property? Thats the name of the interface, isnt it? Shouldn't you access the property of `obj.name`?

Comment: Opps, mistype, yes it was. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<input name="tester" [ngModel]="obj.another?.name"
 (ngModelChange)="obj.another = $event ? { name: $event } : null">
```

Also you might need to change `another? : test2` to `another? : test2 | null`.

Comment: That would not amend the object just create a new object on obj.another so you could not have two fields on the same object, they would overwrite each other.

Comment: Then move logic to the template: `(ngModelChange)="updateObj($event)"`. In `updateObj` you can whatever you want with `obj`.

Comment: Yeah, I though of that, seems a hassle though for just checking if an object is null. I was just wondering if there was a better way.